# Ужасно долгий ответ от функции

Tags: php

Ужасно долгий ответ от функции `file_get_contents`. Я выполняю следующий код

```
$postdata = http_build_query(array(
    'ip' => '' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ''

));
$opts     = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$t        = microtime(true);
$result   = file_get_contents($this->engine_domain . 'GeoIP/get_geo.php', false, $context);
```

Раньше за мгновение получал ответ, а теперь жду по 15 сек. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А что говорит `traceroute` от того хоста на котором выполняется этот скрипт до того хоста на котором расположен сервис ?

Comment: Кажется, тут дело не в php, а в настройках сервера, так как на других сайтах этот код быстро выполняется.

Comment: Может быть, на той стороне сервиса какие-то ограничения по вашему IP из-за частого использования?

Answer (score 1):

Может было-бы проще использовать локальную базу [GeoIP](https://www.php.net/geoip)?

Answer (score 0):

Если здесь есть запросы на другие домены, то дело точно в них. Быть может там ай пи адрес поменяли, или у вас что что с интернетом?